# Lazarus json-rpc client

Tags: client, lazarus, freepascal, json-rpc

What is the easy way to making json-rpc call from freepascal (lazarus)? If it possible with code give some examples. I am read fcl-web but can not find code example.

Comment: How hard have you looked?  Googling `fcl-web` returns a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FCL-Web, which contains a link to https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fcl-web, which includes code snippets and contains a link to https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/fpWeb_Tutorial.  Btw, I think your q is off-topic here at SC because you are basically asking for a tutorial istm.

Comment: Btw, note that the article at https://wiki.freepascal.org/fcl-web contains this reference $(fpcdirectory)\packages\fcl-web\examples\jsonrpc\demo1\wmdemo.pp

Comment: I think these server side cgi application, I need make json-rpc request on client side